# Office 2013 OneDrive Location

Tags: 2013, office

When a user creates a document in Word/Excel 2013 is there a way to change the location of the OneDrive option to my On-Prem SharePoint site?

Additionally, is there a way to add my SharePoint 2013 site in the "Add a Place" list?

Comment: check this one https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Sync-OneDrive-for-Business-or-site-libraries-to-your-computer-23e1f12b-d896-4cb1-a238-f91d19827a16?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA

Comment: Thanks @WaqasSarwarMCSE, I have tried that, and even after syncing with my Mysite, when I click on File>Save from Word, One drive is there and asks me to sign-in.  When I try to "Add a Place" I get the sign-in form and when I provide my company credentials, I don't get anything.